# Cakephp: Update an Array object with equivalent column value in a table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp-1.3

I have stored the below in settings table:

```
Array(
    A => 2, B => 2, C => 0, D => 2,
    E => 2, F => 0, G => 2, H => 0,
    I => 2, J => 0, K => 0, L => 0,
    M => 0, N => 0, O => 0, P => 0,
    Q => 0
)
```

and would like to replace the alias column value to id column value when using in code, so that I get:

```
Array(
    35 => 2, 24 => 2, 14 => 0, 12 => 2,
    22 => 2, 8 => 0, 21 => 2, 17 => 0,
    7 => 2, 10 => 0, 9 => 0, 13 => 0,
    18 => 0, 15 => 0, 16 => 0, 6 => 0, 11 => 0
)
```

Table data:
[image]

Looking for something easier way in Cakephp to achieve this. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

So if you store the data you retrieve from DB in an array like this :

```
$arr1 = Array( 35 => 'A', 24 => 'B', 14 => 'C', 12 => 'D', 22 => 'E', 8 => 'F')
$arr2 = Array( 'A' => 2, 'B' => 2, 'C' => 0, 'D' => '2', 'E' => 2, 'F' => 0)
```

now, we can compare the array's and make the replacement like this:

```
foreach($arr1 as $key=>&$value){
    if(array_key_exists($value, $arr2)){
        $value = $arr2[$value];
    }

}
print_r($arr1);
```

see it in action [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3cb7ab138a0ec37d710ccf2079809a2a8375ffef)

Comment: Thanks @rs007.  I am just storing the second array($arr2) in settings table and would like to get the id from table shown.

Comment: ok, since you stated you need the modified array to use in the code, you will need to fetch data from settings Table($arr2) and the table given ($arr1) correct. once you have those two array's in the memory, it doesen't make a difference how you choose to manipulate as long as you get the desired array as an output.

Comment: Thanks. What if the $arr1 = Array( 35 => 'A', 24 => 'B', 14 => 'C', 12 => 'D', 22 => 'E', 8 => 'F', 52 => 'T', 56 => 'X') . It shouldn't display the additional records.

Comment: ok, so you mean if $arr1 has values which dont have a corresponding key in $arr2 , so in that case one of the options is you can unset that element in the array: so you in the code above you can add an else block and: unset($key), also if you would like to reindex this array then you can do $arr3 = array_values($arr1)

Comment: Correction to the above comment, it's unset($arr1[$key]) and not just $key